# rootScope functions not being called when using ngIdle

Tags: angularjs, rootscope, ng-idle

I am using the [ngIdle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle) library and as the [documentation](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle#getting-started) states there are certain methods that you can call to check for user inactivity, and I have put these on the root scope.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
        alert('you will be logged out');
    });

    $rootScope.$on('IdleStart', function () {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

These functions are never being called and I think that it might be a problem more to do with `$rootscope` rather than the ngidle library.

There are not any errors in console, and the ngidle library is included correctly. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you show more code (like where you configure Idle)? it looks like they run Idle.watch() in the run block which I assume starts a watch. Then they inject Idle into a controller and listen for events there, rather than in the run block. They also configure the intervals in the config block with IdleProvider

Comment: Maybe... the ngidle library is *not* included or configured correctly. Show us a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

For me `ng-idle` works fine using the `$rootScope`. But I wasted some time waiting for the events to fire until I recognized, that the configuration expects ***seconds*** instead of milliseconds ;)

```
app.config(function(IdleProvider) {
    // configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds!
    IdleProvider.timeout(5); // in seconds!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time struggling with this too; none of the events were firing at all. Turns out that you need to call `Idle.watch()` so that the timing starts.

This isn't well documented; documentation is patchy and none of the examples I saw had this. All looked just like the code you have so I couldn't figure out what's wrong until I saw it in the [Getting Started section on the library's GitHub page](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle). It's not explicitly mentioned though, you have to look closely.

```
.run(function(Idle){
    // start watching when the app runs. also starts the Keepalive service by default.
    Idle.watch();
});
```

Then the second catch: once you get auto-logged out once, it will no longer time your session if you login again without reloading the app. You need to call `Idle.watch()` again from your Login method to [reset the timers and start again](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle/wiki/Idle-and-Idleprovider).